# How to Efficiently improve the following update query and why my query should not be used(oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle

i am new user of oracle database and i am trying some experimentations on it.

I have written the following query for update.

Can we improve this query.

I asked my seniors about this query and they said this query is little slower when data is large in this table.

So, i want to understand and get some info why this query is slower and how it can be improved.

```
UPDATE EMP_COMPANY C1
SET SALARY = (SELECT 1.5 * AVG(C2.SALARY)
              FROM EMP_COMPANY
              WHERE C2.CNAME = C1.CNAME)
```

Comment: The query as written will crash because c2 is undefined.  However, that's a minor point.  As far as improving the logic, if name is not a unique identifier, you might not get the results you intended.  Gordon's answer addresses the performance question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your query is quite reasonable for Oracle.  You can improve it by having an index on `EMP_COMPANY(CNAME, SALARY)`.  This index "covers" the subquery, so the data pages do not need to be used for the subquery.

The operation seems a bit strange -- setting a bunch of salaries to a constant within a company.  But that is another matter.

EDIT:

Your query is missing the `c2` alias, so I think you mean:

```
UPDATE EMP_COMPANY C1
SET SALARY = (SELECT 1.5 * AVG(C2.SALARY)
              FROM EMP_COMPANY C2
              WHERE C2.CNAME = C1.CNAME);
```